# Cosa significa "mettere in cassa integrazione"?

Tags: word-meaning, single-words

Cosa significa "mettere in cassa integrazione"? Queste parole mi ricordano di una cassaforte, e non capisco che senso abbia la parola "integrare" in questo contesto. Grazie.

Comment: Il nome completo è cassa integrazione guadagni. Wikipedia ha tutta la spiegazione del funzionamento. Per un chiarimento delle parole "cassa"  ed "integrazione" basta un semplice dizionario: vedi il # **9** su http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/C/cassa.php e il # **1.a** su http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/integrazione/

Comment: @ErikvanDoren: Ma cosa si può "mettere" in cassa integrazione guadagni?

Comment: @Charo, il lavoratore, come specificato nei link ai dizionari "essere in cassa integrazione" "essere messo in cassa integrazione" "mettere qualcuno in cassa integrazione" ecc. come dal primo link: "*Essere in cassa integrazione: usufruire di tale sovvenzione*"

Comment: @ErikvanDoren: Quindi "mettere in cassa integrazione" significa fare che un lavoratore possa ricevere uno stipendio dalla cassa integrazione guadagni?

Comment: @ErikvanDoren: Per me, che non sono italiana, la risposta alla domanda non è così evidente dalla lettura delle voci dei dizionari che hai menzionato.

Comment: È anche interessante e, a mio parere, non così evidente, la domanda su cosa c'entra questa "cassa integrazione" con il concetto di "integrare".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41625/discussion-between-erik-vandoren-and-charo).

Comment: in inglese https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unemployment_benefits_in_Italy#Redundancy_Fund

Comment: @ErikvanDoren: Ho capito il significato di questa prestazione, ma non capisco cosa significhi esattamente "*integrare* lo stipendio del lavoratore". Non vedo che l'OP abbia chiesto semplicemente il significato di "cassa".

Comment: @Charo *Integrare* in questo caso significa *completare* (vedi il significato 1 in http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/I/integrare.shtml). Fondamentalmente, lo stato si impegna a pagare parte dello stipendio del lavoratore per evitare che la ditta debba ricorrere a licenziamenti (e quindi a perdere capitale umano accumulato nella forza lavoro). Se il sistema sembra privo di senso è perché, a mia opinione, lo è, ma nessuno ha detto che la legislazione del lavoro in Italia sia perfetta, anzi...

Comment: @ErikvanDoren: Finalmente scriverai la risposta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il nome completo è **Cassa Integrazione Guadagni** (salari).

Wikipedia ha tutta la spiegazione del funzionamento nelle varie lingue e rimando a quella per i dettagli.

Sostanzialmente è un fondo che permette ai lavoratori che sono in condizione di orario ridotto, o lasciati a casa, perché la loro ditta si trova in difficoltà economiche, di ricevere una sovvenzione da parte dello stato che va ad "integrare" (ad aggiungersi) il loro stipendio ridotto.

Per un chiarimento delle parole "cassa","integrazione" e "guadagni":

da [dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/C/cassa.php](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/C/cassa.php)

> **cassa** [càs-sa] s.f.
>
> **9** ECON Istituzione finanziaria pubblica creata per vari scopi, spec. previdenziali: *c. assistenza malattie; c. assistenza infortuni*
>   || Istituto bancario o finanziario: *c. di risparmio, c. artigiana
>   || **Cassa del, per il Mezzogiorno**, per la promozione economica e sociale dell'Italia meridionale
>   || **Cassa integrazione salari, cassa integrazione**, organismo di previdenza sociale che stipendia per periodi limitati lavoratori sospesi a tempo da aziende in difficoltà transitorie
>   || **Essere in cassa integrazione**, usufruire di tale sovvenzione

da [treccani.it/vocabolario/integrazione](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/integrazione)

> **integrazióne** s. f. [dal lat. integratio -onis, con influenza, nel sign. 3, dell’ingl. integration].
>
> **1.** In senso generico, il fatto di integrare, di rendere intero, pieno, perfetto ciò che è incompleto o insufficiente a un determinato scopo, aggiungendo quanto è necessario
>
> Con accezioni specifiche: **a.** *Cassa i. (propr. cassa i. guadagni)*, nel linguaggio sindacale, lo speciale fondo che corrisponde l’i. salariale, cioè una somma pari all’80% della retribuzione globale, agli operai dipendenti da imprese industriali, o ai lavoratori dell’edilizia e affini, che effettuino prestazioni di lavoro a orario ridotto, per contrazione o sospensione dell’attività produttiva dovuta a fatti aziendali o a crisi economiche settoriali o locali: *mettere, essere, trovarsi in cassa integrazione*.

e da [dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/G/guadagno.php](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/G/guadagno.php)

> **guadagno**
>   [gua-dà-gno]
>   s.m. (pl. -gni)
>
> **2** Ciò che si riceve come compenso per un'attività, una prestazione e sim.

Mettere il lavoratore in cassa integrazione significa che la ditta richiede (ed ottiene) che lo stato sovvenzioni lo stipendio dei lavoratori perché si trova in difficoltà.  Quando la richiesta è accettata il lavoratore "è in cassa integrazione"